# separate oauth2 and web server

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-session

Suppose my site is `example.com`

When a user at a `client.com` wants to login via `example.com` (with oauth2)

1. He comes to `oauth.example.com/authorize` and `oauth.example.com` knows he's not signed in to `web.example.com` .
2. `oauth.example.com` redirects him to `web.example.com`
3. he logs into `web.example.com` then gets redirect back to `oauth.example.com`
4. `oauth.example.com` somehow knows that he is logged into `web.example.com`
5. `oauth.example.com` does its oauth2 magic and sends him back to `client.com`

My question is, how should `oauth.example.com` should detect if a user is logged in or not with `web.example.com` .

I'm considering to let `web.example.com` to store session data in DB, and have `oauth.example.com` to look up the db.

My concern is that when session expires (without user explicitly logging out), it might be possible for the two servers get out of time-sync.

A user (A) might refresh `web.example.com` and find out his session is expired and leave the computer open.
Another user (B) might click `login with example.com` and `oauth.example.com` might consider `(A)` user is still logged in (because time is not well synchronized).

Would synchronizing clock with nptd be best I could do?
Or should I scrap this idea and come up with something else?

- implementation detail: I'm considering spring-session-jdbc, and it unfortunately doesn't remove session data on every expiration.

Answer (score 0):

Your `oauth.example.com` should provide the login page. The `oauth.example.com` must be Authorization server ([rfc6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.2)). When the `web.example.com` request user login, the login url should redirect to the `oauth.example.com` login page.

The `oauth.example.com` provider login authentication (identity verify), then back the `web.example.com`. If login success, the `web.example.com` will switch token with `oauth.example.com`.

> I'm considering to let web.example.com to store session data in DB, and have oauth.example.com to look up the db.

You can treat the Oauth access token and Oauth refresh token as cookies or a session id for `oauth.example.com` in your `web.example.com` server.

> My concern is that when session expires (without user explicitly logging out), it might be possible for the two servers get out of time-sync.

The `oauth.example.com` must have revoke token api.